# How to reset timer whenever a pushbutton is clicked

Tags: python-3.x, timer, pyqt5

I have two pushbuttons in my code when the function below runs it starts a timer and disables the other pushbutton. Now to briefly break down what is happening:
The OuterSwitch Button is pressed which checks to make sure the inner door is shut and then it opens the outer door. When the OuterSwitch button is pressed again it now disables the innerswitch push button and locks the outer door. This also starts a timer for 3 seconds. Now if I press the outerswitch to open the outer door in this time, I would like it to stop the timer and reset it so when i press to close the door again it starts from 3 seconds. Currently when I close the door again it just runs multiple timers in parallel. I've been trying to no avail, hoping someone could guide me in how I can do this? I hope this makes sense if any more information is required please ask.

```
import sys
import board
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import time
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread


Outer = 22
Inner = 27
GPIO.setup(Outer,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Inner,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Inner,GPIO.HIGH)




class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.Timer = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.Timer.setObjectName("Timer")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Timer)
        self.OuterSwitch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.OuterSwitch.setObjectName("OuterSwitch")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.OuterSwitch)
        self.InnerSwitch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.InnerSwitch.setObjectName("InnerSwitch")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.InnerSwitch)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)




    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.OuterSwitch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Outer Door"))
        self.InnerSwitch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Inner Door"))





class ControlMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.OuterSwitch.clicked.connect(self.OuterControl)
        self.ui.InnerSwitch.clicked.connect(self.InnerControl)


    def OuterControl(self):
        if GPIO.input(Inner)==0: #InnerDoorOpen
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH),print("Please Close Inner Door")
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) ==1: #Outer Door Close
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Close Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.LOW) #Open Outer Door
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) == 0: #OuterDoor Open
            self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000,partial(self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled,True))
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH) #Close OuterDoor




    def  InnerControl(self):
        if GPIO.input(Outer)==0: #Outer Open
            return GPIO.output(Inner,GPIO.HIGH), print("Please Close Outer Door")
        elif GPIO.input(Inner) ==1: #Inner Door Close
            self.ui.InnerSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Close Inner Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            return GPIO.output(Inner,GPIO.LOW) #Open Inner
        elif GPIO.input(Inner) ==0:
            self.ui.InnerSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Inner Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            return GPIO.output(Inner,GPIO.HIGH) #Close Inner





        #Troubleshoot-comment in
##    sys.excepthook=sys.excepthook
##    def exception_hook(exctype,value,traceback):
##        print(exctype,value,traceback)
##        sys.exit(1)
##    sys.excepthook=exception_hook




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySW = ControlMainWindow()
    mySW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the part of the code which controls the outer door.

```
def OuterControl(self):
        if GPIO.input(Inner)==0: #InnerDoorOpen
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH),print("Please Close Inner Door")
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) ==1: #Outer Door Close
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Close Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.LOW) #Open Outer Door
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) == 0: #OuterDoor Open
            self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000,partial(self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled,True))
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH) #Close OuterDoor
```

Comment: Ok So I have become aware that SingleShot timers cannot be reset, in a simple way as they are not assigned to anything, but I am sure there must be another way. can Anyone Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this:
So what I did was create a seperate timer which can be killed and set it to single shot. I then set a callable function which would enable the innerswitch to be set as true/active. Only if the timer is up.. see attached code:

```
class ControlMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.OuterSwitch.clicked.connect(self.OuterControl)
        self.ui.InnerSwitch.clicked.connect(self.InnerControl)

        self.current_timer = None

    def starttimer(self):
        if self.current_timer:
            self.current_timer.stop()
            self.current_timer.deleteLater()
        self.current_timer=QtCore.QTimer()
        self.current_timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.current_timer.start(3000)
        self.current_timer.timeout.connect(self.InnerSwitchOn)

    def InnerSwitchOn(self):   
        self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled(True)

    def OuterControl(self):
        if GPIO.input(Inner)==0: #InnerDoorOpen
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH),print("Please Close Inner Door")
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) ==1: #Outer Door Close
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Close Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.LOW) #Open Outer Door
        elif GPIO.input(Outer) == 0: #OuterDoor Open
            self.ui.InnerSwitch.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.OuterSwitch.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open Outer Door",None))
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            self.starttimer()
            return GPIO.output(Outer,GPIO.HIGH) #Close OuterDoor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it `QTimeLine` class provides a timeline for controlling animations.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 230)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTimer.singleShot vs. QTimeLine")

        layV = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layV)
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber()  
        self.i = 0        
        layH = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lblSingleShot = QLabel("QTimer.singleShot")
        self.lblSingleShot.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Sunken)
        self.lblTimeLine   = QLabel("QTimeLine")
        self.lblTimeLine.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Sunken)
        layH.addWidget(self.lblSingleShot)
        layH.addWidget(self.lblTimeLine)

        self.btnStart = QPushButton("Start Timer", clicked=self.startTimer)

        layV.addWidget(self.lcd)
        layV.addLayout(layH)
        layV.addWidget(self.btnStart)

        self.timer = QTimer()  
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateData)        

        self.timeLine = QTimeLine(3000)                       # <---
        self.timeLine.setFrameRange(0, 2)  
        self.timeLine.setUpdateInterval(1000)
        self.timeLine.finished.connect(self.finishTimeLine)   # <---

    def finishTimeLine(self):                                 # <---
        self.lblTimeLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; color: white;") 

    def startTimer(self):
        if self.btnStart.text() == "Start Timer":
            self.i = 1
            self.lcd.display(self.i)
            self.timer.start(1000) 
            self.btnStart.setText("Stop Timer")
            QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.onShow)
            self.lblSingleShot.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
            self.lblSingleShot.setText("QTimer.singleShot")
            self.lblTimeLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
            self.lblTimeLine.setText("QTimeLine")

            self.timeLine.start()                             # <---
        else:
            self.btnStart.setText("Start Timer")
            self.timer.stop()
            self.timeLine.stop()                              # <---
            self.lblTimeLine.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: white;")
            self.lblTimeLine.setText("QTimeLine - Stop")
        self.i = 1            

    def updateData(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.lcd.display(self.i)

    def onShow(self):
        self.lblSingleShot.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; color: white;")    
        self.lblSingleShot.setText("<b>def onShow() - Start.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @S.Nick Thanks for the reply,  I'm still not quite sure how I can implement that into my code. I am going to update the question with my full code.