# Reset or reinitialize a PyQt singleShot Timer to prevent function call

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtimer

Is there a wy to reset a singleshot Timer?
I set the singleShot timer to 5000ms and want to reset the timer by clicking a button so the timer starts again to count.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFrame, QLabel, QWidget 
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainFrame = QFrame(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainFrame.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainFrame)
        self.vLay = QVBoxLayout(self.mainFrame)
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('press me')
        self.button2 = QPushButton()
        self.button2.setText('Stop')
        self.label = QLabel(self.mainFrame)
        self.label.setText('testLabel')
        self.vLay.addWidget(self.button)
        self.vLay.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.vLay.addWidget(self.label)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.singleShot(5000, self.shot)
        self.label.setText('running')

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.stopTimer)

    def resetTimer(self):
        self.label.setText('reseted')
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.singleShot(5000, self.shot) 
    
    def stopTimer(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.label.setText('stopped')

    def shot(self):
        self.label.setText('shot')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If i press the resetButton it seems that a new Timer would initialize but i want to reset the current timer.

Comment: a single shot timer is exactly what it's name suggests, it's meant to fire off exactly once and then never again. What you could do is use a thread to count down for you and whenever you click the resetbutton, change the value of the countdown in the thread.

Comment: If you really want to stick with the timer though maybe this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496405/how-to-reset-timer-whenever-a-pushbutton-is-clicked

Comment: @Andew There is absolutely ***no*** need for threading for a simple timer reset. You just need to use the proper functions.

Comment: @musicamante what are the proper functions to do something like this?

Comment: @Andew see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QTimer.singleShot()` is a *static* function that creates a *new* single shot timer.

You are not actually using the QTimer instance you've created, in fact you create a new timer every time you call that function.

You have to *set* the `singleShot` property on the QTimer instance, connect it to the required slot, and start *that* timer:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.shot)
        self.timer.start()

    def resetTimer(self):
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.label.setText('reset')
        else:
            self.label.setText('restarted')
        # start() will always restart the timer, no matter if it was active
        # or not, and will use the previously set interval (set with 
        # setInterval() or the last start() call
        self.timer.start()
```

An alternative and shorter syntax:

```
        self.timer = QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.shot)
        self.timer.start(5000)
```

Comment: @Andew Well, you can test it and see it for your own :-) That part of the explanation might be confusing, but it just points out that calling `start()` on a singleShot timer won't change that property, so it will only be activated once *for every time you call `start()`*.

Comment: yes you are right. I guess I was just confused by the documentation, but I should have tried it first before posting my answer.

Comment: I removed my post since yours better answers the question :)

Comment: @musicamante perfect. i didn't know that setSingleShot() is different from QTimer.singleShot(). Thanks you very much.

Comment: @Robert You're welcome. Always check the documentation to know if you're using static functions (in Qt docs they are always tagged with a `[static]` label next to the definition), and remember that they always return (or, at least, create) a *new* instance using the provided arguments. Also, remember that if an answer solves your question, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mark. Now I did. On my second screen I always have open the docs but sometimes it is very hard to understand. I'm from Germany. Good to know about static functions. Thank you

Comment: @Robert well, I'm not that far from you, as I'm italian. We generally have poor English education and our language roots are even farther than yours from English. Nonetheless, that's the "official" programming language, and we've to stick with it, even if we might not like it as we "should". But, it **is** a *language*, and, as with any language (including programming) it's important to contextualize it considering how it was born and evolved. "Semantic" is important for *any* language, even (and especially) if it's not our own. The cool thing is that any language is, actually, "programming".